# Disabling TLS 1.0 in sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, tls

Critical Update option shows **Disabling older TLS** Option in Production Org but not in Sandbox Org?What could be the reason?

[image]

Does it mean Sandbox has already disabled TLS 1.0 it as mentioned here?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it is mentioned ,last year june was the deadline for sandboxes for auto activation of the TLS 1.1 . Hence all the sandboxes instances now has TLS1.1 activated now and there is no way to enable or disable it .

The Production Orgs also we have till july 27th 2017 for auto activation .

Comment: Its july 22nd ri8?For production Orgs?

Comment: 44days more days for Production Org to get auto activated