# How to find whether my callout is using TLS 1.0 or 1.1?

Tags: callout, tls

We have just upgraded our SAP server to support TLS 1.1. Now, I need to find out using which protocol version my callouts are going to SAP.

I have checked debug log but did not any such information. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: If you set it up in a sandbox and successfully connect to SAP you'll know it's not TLS 1.0 as 1.0 was disabled in all sandbox environments last year.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178054/disabling-tls-1-0-in-sandbox

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Knowledgebase article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214850&type=1), TLS 1.2 was supported for Apex callouts as of summer 2015.

> Apex callouts, Workflow outbound messaging, Delegated Authentication,
>   and other HTTPS callouts now support TLS (Transport Layer Security)
>   1.1, TLS 1.2 ...

Answer (score 1):

You can view `Login History` from `Setup->Manage Users-> Login History` how users are accessing Salesforce and which TLS protocol they are using.

[image: Login History]

Comment: This question is specifically asking about outgoing http requests *from* SFDC. This list is for requests *to* SFDC

Answer (score 1):

Based on the TLS 1.1 Disablement docs https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321556&type=1&mode=1

TLS 1.1 is disabled for both inbound and outbound requests. *ANY* https connection to salesforce will require TLS 1.2 as of late 2019.