# Apex callouts - TLS ciphersuite

Tags: apex, httprequest, tls

I'm working on an integration with Salesforce using Apex code to make outgoing API calls. One of our users is asking what cipher is being used. Is there any way to figure this out? Some way of viewing the TLS handshake information for requests going out from Apex code.

Comment: If memory serves both servers negotiate on a cipher suite that they can both work with. This answer has a link to the list of ciphers Salesforce supports: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/304498/21249

Comment: @Kasper I'm not really looking for what ciphers are supported. I'm looking for what cipher actually ends up being selected. If I make an API call from my local machine I can using something like Fiddler to see what cipher was used. I'd like to capture the same from the calls being made from Apex code in Salesforce.

Comment: Sorry James, can't help you then. I wouldn't know if the information is available but I doubt it since it's generally an uninteresting implementation detail. As long as the supported cypers are save you're encryption should be too.